# Parse an OWL file using RDFLib generetes errors

Tags: owl, rdflib

Here's the code snippet where I'm facing issues:

```
from rdflib import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse('./Ontology/sample.owl', format='owl')
```

And I'm getting an error:

> Error: raise PluginException("No plugin registered for (%s, %s)" %
> (name, kind)) rdflib.plugin.PluginException: No plugin registered for
> (owl, <class 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>)

When I try using a different format:

```
g.parse('./Ontology/sample.owl', format='xml')
```

I encounter another error:

> Error: xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: file://sample.owl:1:0:
> not well-formed (invalid token)

Tried formats OWL, XML, and `application/rdf+xml`, but none worked.

Comment: there is no `owl` format in `rdflib`, see https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/plugin_parsers.html - as you already tried `xml` which maps to the `RDFXML` serialization, and this failed, the question is in what syntax your OWL ontology is made of. Are you sure this is `RDF/XML`? How did you create the ontology? Note, for `RDF/XML` is has to be a self-contained valid XML file.